# baseURL not used in request url

Tags: javascript, axios, environment-variables

I'm using **Axios** (with **react** and **express**). I have a `baseURL` in my *.env-file*.

When I `console.log(process.env.BASE_URL)` I get the url from *.env* in my terminal: **localhost:3000/api** .

But in my requests **(chrome dev tools > network > call > header)** only: **localhost:3000** (without **/api**) is used.

When I hardcode the `baseURL`, instead of using *.env-file* everything works. So is is a problem with my *.env-file*? Or `axios`? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Here is relevant code:

```
//.env
BASE_URL=http://localhost:3000/api

//using axios
require("dotenv").config();
...

const Provider = () => {
...
  const contextAxios = axios.create({ baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL }); //not working
  //const contextAxios = axios.create({ baseURL: http://localshost:3000/api }) -> works

   useEffect(() => {
    const getProt = async() => {
      const { data } = await contextAxios.get('/prot');
      ...
    };
    getProt();
  }, []); 
 ...
};
```

Comment: See https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to ensure your .env setup has 'REACT_APP_BASE_URL' to work, if you don't have 'REACT_APP_' it won't work.
2. Restart node server to test.
3. Have you tried reinstalling the npm module?

```
# with npm 
npm install dotenv
 
# or with Yarn 
yarn add dotenv
```

Then you can simply require it like you have done. Also restart your node server after making changes to you .env config otherwise they won't update (Found that out the hard way myself...! :)

```
//Then require like you have done and what you have should work.
require('dotenv').config()
```